# reformat file by external tool before writing file in vim

Tags: vim

I want the vim to call ':!gn format BUILD.gn' when I write BUILD.gn file, my .vimrc is (version 1)

```
autocmd BufWritePre  *.{gn,gni} call GnFormat()
function! GnForamt()
  exec '!gn format %'
endfunction
```

But it can not work when I press ':w", it shows error message as

```
Error detected while processing BufWrite Autocommands for "*.gn":
"BUILD.gn" 67L, 1423C written
```

How to show more detail debug information and what's the correct method to call external format tool?

I also tried following method, but failed too (version 2)

```
autocmd BufWritePre  *.{gn,gni} call GnFormat()
function! GnForamt()
  exec '%!gn format --stdin'
endfunction
```

The output result of version 2 .vimrc of `:11verbose w` is

```
Executing BufWrite Autocommands for "*.{gn,gni}"
autocommand call GnFormat()
Error detected while processing BufWrite Autocommands for "*.{gn,gni}":
"BUILD.gn" 27L, 538C written
Executing BufWritePost Autocommands for "*"
autocommand cal s:record(expand('<abuf>', 1))
Executing BufWritePost Autocommands for "*"
autocommand call s:BufWritePostHook(expand('<afile>', 1))
```

And in the version 2, I can use `:call GnForamt()` manually to reformat the buffer without any error message.

Just know the reason

```
autocmd BufWritePre  *.{gn,gni} call GnFormat()
function! GnFormat()   " <--- typo of Format as Foramt
  exec '%!gn format --stdin'
endfunction
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `*.gn,*.gni` as filetype?

Comment: It can changed to BUILD.gn, but still not workable, you can try it.

Comment: don't worry `*.{gn,gni}` seems to work depending on your output. It is just new for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `:debug w` (see `:h debug`) or `:13verbose w`. See `:h verbose` and `:h 'verbose'`.

`:[level]verbose` will allow you to activate verbose mode for a single action